# is there a way to rewrite function to class code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this code

```
const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");

const content = useRef(null);

function toggleAccordion() {
  setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
  setHeightState(
    setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    );
 }
```

can i rewrite this in class component ? (how can i rewrite this functional code into class component react code ?)

```
export default class Accordion extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      setActive,
      setActiveState
    }
  }

  toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive )
  }
}
```

how can i setActive and setActiveState to toggle on or off ?

Comment: setActiveState isn't a piece of state.  It's a method for changing state.  You can just use setState for changing state in class components.

Comment: so how can i use that method in class component ?

Answer (score 0):

When using class component, updating state is achieved using the setState function. An object is passed into it, where all the state variables that needs to be updated can be added , and those gets updated.

```
export default class Accordion extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          setActive:"",
          setHeight:"0px"
        }
      }
    
      toggleAccordion() {
        let newState = {...this.state,
        setActive:this.state.setActive === "" ? "active" : "",
        setHeight:this.state.setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`}
        this.setState(newState);
      }
}
```